# How do I replicate this series of numbers in my practice project

Tags: node-editor, interface, geometry-nodes, performance

so I followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/12NQOTgQt58) to make a digital clock and I hit a snag around time 4:07 when I wanted to replicate the numbers displayed in this first screenshot.

I tried to use the 'join strings' node and a bunch of other things but it did not work. I have attached the screenshot to this post. Here's the [link](https://we.tl/t-kkxjgTxKAo) to the blend file.

[image: screenshot of the numbers I want to replicate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "string to curves" node should be outside of the "Timer" group:

[image]

Something like this:

[image]

If, from this group, you output a geometry for each time part, you can't join them as "string" after that.

Comment: Thank you @lemon!!! So sorry I didn't respond earlier : (. I gave up on the project, lol. But I know I shouldn't have that attitude though, just moved on to another one, but I tried it and it worked! Thanks for helping a noob like me!